why in the question below is theta defined over a limited domain?
I am working for an exam so I am unable to transcript in this exact moment the problem of which I will put the image below, my question is why are we defining the  domain of theta? is it to  keep the value under the root positive? yet I sill don't see how currently. (attempted transcription: The image shows the problem:

Use the substitution $x = 3 \sin\theta, 0 < \theta < π/2$, to write
$\sqrt{9-x^2}$ as a trigonometric function of $\theta$

Thanks very much!


They could have given you a different domain of $\theta$. It's not that important: give the main question a go first. It's good to always check if you're taking a square root of a positive thing, and handling absolute values and so and so on, but you won't know if you'll need that or not until you try the question!

As @FShrike mentioned, the domain of $\theta$ is not particularly important; the chosen domain simply helps express the final solution without needing to consider the potential cases. They selected for you a specific case.

what if they did not specify the domain what owed be the resulting possible cases and how to solve them?

@FedericoRuck Note $\sqrt{9-x^2}$ makes sense for $-3\le x\le 3$. So $3\sin\theta$ for any value of $\theta$ "works". But there is some subtlety - because your answer might be different! Meaning no offence to Abdellah, I'm surprised you've accepted the answer. Have you managed to solve the question yet?

hi what do you mean?

After the change of variable, you obtain $\sqrt{cos(\theta)^2}$. Therefore, you need to analyze the sign of the cosine function. The cases are $\theta \in [2k\pi -\frac{\pi}{2}, 2k\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}]$ (cos $\geq 0$) and $\theta \in [2k\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}, 2k\pi + \frac{3\pi}{2}]$ (cos $\leq 0$).

Let $x=3\sin\theta$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{9-x^2} &= \sqrt{9 - 9\sin^2\theta},\\
&= \sqrt{9}\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta},\\
&= 3 \sqrt{\cos^2\theta},\\
&= 3 |\cos\theta|.
\end{align}
$$
Because $\cos\theta \geq 0$ when $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$, we can discard the absolute value; hence,
$$
\sqrt{9-x^2} = 3\cos\theta. 
$$
